# Spark text parsing with dynamic delimiter

Tags: apache-spark

I have text file which looks like:

```
:1: some first row of first attribute
second row of first attribute
:55: first row of fifty fifth 
:100: some other text
also other
another one
```

I would like to parse it such manner:

```
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| AttrNr   | Row                               |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|   1      | some first row of first attribute |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|   1      | second row of first attribute     |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|   1      | 3rd value with test: 1,2,3        |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
|  55      | first row of fifty fifth          |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 100      | some other text                   |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 100      | also other                        |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
| 100      | another one                       |
+----------+-----------------------------------+
```

Parsing should be done according :n: delimeter. ":" symbol might appear in values.

Answer (score 0):

The final output can be achieved by using a set of Window functions that are available on Spark but your data lacks a lot of essential details like a partitioning column, a column with which we can order the data to know which row comes after the first one.

Assuming you are working on a distributed system here the following answer might not work at all. It works for the provided example but things will be different when you are in a distributed environment with a huge file.

Creating a `DataFrame` from the text file:

1. Reading the text file as an RDD:

```scala
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      (":1: some first row of first attribute"),
      ("second row of first attribute"),
      (":55: first row of fifty fifth"),
      (":100: some other text"),
      ("also other"),
      ("another one")
))

// Or use spark.sparkContext.textFile if you are reading from a file
```

2. Iterate over the RDD to split the columns in the required format and generate a DataFrame

```scala
val df = rdd.map{ c=>
   if(c.startsWith(":")) (c.split(" ", 2)(0), c.split(" ", 2)(1))
   else (null.asInstanceOf[String], c )
}.toDF("AttrNr", "Row")

//df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [AttrNr: string, Row: string]

df.show(false)
// +------+---------------------------------+
// |AttrNr|Row                              |
// +------+---------------------------------+
// |:1:   |some first row of first attribute|
// |null  |second row of first attribute    |
// |:55:  |first row of fifty fifth         |
// |:100: |some other text                  |
// |null  |also other                       |
// |null  |another one                      |
// +------+---------------------------------+
```

3. The following set of commands are just a hack and are not performance effective at all and shouldn't be used in a production-like environment. `last` provides your the last not null column. Partition and ordering is done manually here because your data does not provide those set of columns.

```scala
df.withColumn("p", lit(1))
  .withColumn("AttrNr", 
  last($"AttrNr", true).over(Window.partitionBy($"p").orderBy(lit(1)).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)  ) )

// +------+---------------------------------+
// |AttrNr|Row                              |
// +------+---------------------------------+
// |:1:   |some first row of first attribute|
// |:1:   |second row of first attribute    |
// |:55:  |first row of fifty fifth         |
// |:100: |some other text                  |
// |:100: |also other                       |
// |:100: |another one                      |
// +------+---------------------------------+
```

Comment: ":" symbol might appear in values! 3rd value with test: 1,2,3

Comment: @domisj Yes that's taken care of. I'm not splitting on `:`. As long as there's a space after `:1:`, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I solved it with SQL. But I was wondering maybe it's more simple way. I'm using spark 2.3 without high order functions.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val df = Seq((":1: some first row of first attribute"),
      ("second row of first attribute"),
      ("3rd value with test: 1,2,3"),
      (":55: first row of fifty fifth"),
      (":100: some other text"),
      ("also other"),
      ("another one")).toDF("_c0")

df.createOrReplaceTempView("test1")

spark.sql("""select _c0, split(_c0, ":") arr from test1""").createOrReplaceTempView("test2")

val testDF = spark.sql("""
select arr[1] t0, 
       cast(arr[1] as int) t1, 
       case when arr[1] = cast(arr[1] as int) 
                 then replace(concat_ws(":",arr),concat(concat(":",arr[1]),":"),"") 
                 else concat_ws(":",arr) 
                 end Row 
,monotonically_increasing_id() mrn
from test2""")

val fnc = Window.orderBy("mrn")

val testDF2 = testDF.withColumn("AttrNr", last('t1,true).over(fnc))

testDF2.drop("t0","t1","mrn").show(false)

+----------------------------------+------+
|Row                               |AttrNr|
+----------------------------------+------+
| some first row of first attribute|1     |
|second row of first attribute     |1     |
|3rd value with test: 1,2,3        |1     |
| first row of fifty fifth         |55    |
| some other text                  |100   |
|also other                        |100   |
|another one                       |100   |
+----------------------------------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Column "AttrNr" can be received with "regexp_extract" function:

```
df
  .withColumn("AttrNr", regexp_extract($"_c0", "^:([\\d].*):", 0))
  .withColumn("Row", when(length($"AttrNr") === lit(0), $"_c0").otherwise(expr("substring(_c0, length(AttrNr) + 2)")))
  .withColumn("AttrNr", when(length($"AttrNr") === lit(0), null.asInstanceOf[String]).otherwise(expr("substring(_c0, 2, length(AttrNr) - 2)")))

  // Window with no partitioning, bad for performance
  .withColumn("AttrNr", last($"AttrNr", true).over(Window.orderBy(lit(1)).rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)))
  .drop("_c0")
```